# Is there a way to inform the screen reader about a transition to a new section on the same page?

Tags: html, accessibility, transition, scrollto, wai-aria

I have a page that has 2 steps to register a user.

After a user has filled out all fields of the first section, he needs to confirm the "Terms and Conditions" and press a button to confirm it.
After he has pressed the button, first section is becomes readOnly and the second section (more fields to fill) appears at the bottom of the page and the page does a scrollTo this new section.

I need to inform the screen reader that there is a new section on the same page but I don't know who can I do it.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you jumping the user to a named anchor on the page, or just scrolling the viewport? Also, do you have  URL to a demo so I can test it?

Comment: Guys, this is an example that has the nearest implementation: [Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/yz29fxnv/3/) @aardrian I'm scrolling the viewport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html have an empty span/div with aria-live="assertive". In your button click function, add the text you want the reader to announce to that span.

(This is the same function where you will be taking focus to that section.)

Don't forget to empty it outside the function to make it announce properly next time also.

Aria-assertive text will be announced each time it is changed.

Eg.
In HTML

```
<span id="announce" aria-live="assertive"></span>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

In javascript

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
$("#announce").text("Scrolled to a new section");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is about focus management. You need somewhere to anchor focus that makes sense to the user and you need to then move that focus.

This is not an ideal solution overall, but lacking context for the larger objective I'll give you the bits to get this part functional / useful.

First, add this style so you can see where the focus is going (you can remove/change it later):

```
*:focus {
  outline: 2px solid #f00;
}
```

Now as you tab through the page you can see where the focus lives.

Then in your script where you create the new form (I recommend you actually just hide this section and display it instead of writing it in via JS, but I understand this may be a demo), update the `<h3>` to be focusable by adding an `id` attribute and then a `tabindex` so that you can drop focus on it. I use the `<h3>` you already have since it provides the context for the user and in this case overrides my general distaste for using `tabindex` on non-interactive elements.

```
<h3 id="second" tabindex="0">
```

Then add bit of script after your `setTimeout()` that moves the focus to that element (thereby ensuring it has been rendered and can receive focus):

```
var secondForm = document.getElementById('second');
secondForm.focus();
```

Now when you click the "Continue!" button, the page scrolls and the heading will receive focus, get announced (you can add instruction text, etc), and the user may continue.

You will probably need to massage the script a bit, maybe stuffing it in its own timer function to be certain it only fires when you want, but overall the general concept is in there.

I [made a pen to demo it](http://codepen.io/aardrian/debug/AXRROo).

Comment: If you're focusing programmatically, you can use `tabindex="-1"` to keep the element out of the natural tabbing order.

Comment: Agreed, and that may be a better approach. But if the element isn't even there yet, I figured it was appropriate to drop it into the element and leave it for later tabbing to maintain expectations. Does not mean it is right, just the logic I had.