# self disable button, accessibility

Tags: html, firefox, accessibility, wai-aria, nvda

is there a way to don't read 'unavailable' or 'dimmed' in a self-disable-button?

See the example [Example](http://codepen.io/santospro/pen/ZpzaLy)

```
var saveBtn = document.getElementById("saveBtn");
var helper = document.getElementById("helper");
var content = document.getElementById("content");
saveBtn.onclick = function(e) {
  saveBtn.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
  saveBtn.setAttribute("aria-disabled", true);
  content.innerHTML = 'Lorem input a lot of stuffs';
  helper.innerHTML = "Content added, please read it";
  setTimeout(function(){
    helper.innerHTML = "";
    saveBtn.removeAttribute("disabled");
    saveBtn.setAttribute("aria-disabled", false);
  }, 5000);
};
```

- Voice only says: 'Content added, please read it'
- NVDA says: 'Content added, please read it. **Unavailable**'

I know that it is happening because the button still having focus. But, I need to find a solution for that because I can't modify the current behavior of my page.

I'm using the html helper to inform transitions as you can see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38137593/3438124.

Sorry for ugly code, this is only to simulate my real behavior.

Thank you guys!

Comment: There is the full example: https://jsfiddle.net/yz29fxnv/5/

Answer (score 2):

You will need to move focus to the new element. Give it `tabindex=0` and then use `focus()`.

`aria-live` is for when you want to have the screen reader speak changes for the content area with the `aria-live` attribute. Since you use it on a sibling div, you are missing the opportunity for it to just do what it does. Alternative, you can skip the `tabindex`/`focus()` approach and just put `aria-live` on a container for your new content.

Also, you can ditch the `aria-disabled` and just lean on `disabled` for the button. `aria-disabled` is for elements that otherwise do not support `disabled`.

Comment: Hi @aardian , thank you for answer. I updated my `jsfiddle` example to add the `aria-live` on the parent container, but the result is the same. NVDA reads: 'This is my other big section. Unavailable'. Please take a look of my updated example: https://jsfiddle.net/yz29fxnv/6/

Comment: You did not move the focus to the new element, so focus stays on the `<button>`, reading its change after it reads the `aria-live` target. See the first sentence of my answer. Dump all the `aria-live` since I only suggested it as an alternative. Disable the button after you move focus, since NVDA announces the change as soon as you do it, before you can move focus. Eg: https://jsfiddle.net/qmfj1wp5/2/

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question when you said "I know that it is happening because the button still having focus" and then aardrian pointed it out explicitly when he said "You will need to move focus to the new element".

Keep in mind, though, that whether the focus remains on a disabled object is totally up to the user agent (browser). Some browsers leave the focus on the disabled object and others move it to the parent.

aardrian's comment about using `tabindex` was if you wanted to move the focus to an object that is not normally focusable (ie, if it's an element you can't normally TAB to).  So if you want to move the focus to some simple text (just to get it off the button), then I'd tweak aardrian's suggestion and use `tabindex='-1'` instead of `tabindex='0'`.  That will allow you to call focus() on that element but won't allow the user to TAB to it.

If you want to move the focus to another button on the page, or some other element that can naturally receive focus (checkbox, input field, etc), then you don't need `tabindex`.

If you end up moving the focus to the text that was just added, then you don't really need `aria-live` because the screen reader will read the text that you just focused to.  But that's only relative to the example you posted, which I understand is just a sample to show the problem.  Your real app might not be adding text.

And I want to second aardrian's recommendation of *not* setting `aria-disabled` when you're already using the `disabled` property.  It's superfluous.  The `aria-disabled` property is for when you're simulating a disabled object.

Comment: I'm agree with both of you. I appreciate your comments and suggestions. But my really question is why Voice Over doesn't read 'Unavailable'? which one is wrong?

Comment: "Wrong" is a subjective word in this case.  The user agent decides how to treat self-disabled objects.  You'd have to discuss this with Apple to see why they chose to implement it the way they did.

Comment: Yes. "Unavailable" is NVDA's way of announcing that something is disabled. Unfortunately, if the button becomes disabled immediately after its action is triggered, NVDA's immediate announcement of "unavailable" gives the impression that the button press 'failed'. This may be why Apple chose to do it differently.

Answer (score 0):

How the text is read varies reader to reader. None is right or wrong. If you want the text being read out to be same and consistent across the readers..Do a little workaround. Add an aria-label="desired text" to your button. This will override anything that is present inside the button tag.

eg

```
<button aria-label="desired text button">This text will be ignored</button>
```

Nvda will read the button as "desired text button". Text inside button is ignored. Now you can handle(add/remove) the disabled and aria-label attribute with JS.

In the context of your question you can try:

Instead of:

```
helper.innerHTML = "Content added, please read it";
```

Try using:

```
saveBtn.setAttribute("aria-label", "Content added, please read it.");
setTimeout(function(){
saveBtn.removeAttribute("aria-label");}, 5000);
```

Then the text will be same across the readers.